# How to configure the TLS Inspection and IDPS in Azure Firewall Premium

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-virtual-network

I want to enable the TLS Inspection and IDPS premium features of Azure Firewall Policy using the terraform. For that I have followed the articles https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/premium-certificates and https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/firewall_policy.

```
# Create root CA
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout rootCA.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out rootCA.crt -subj '/C=US/ST=US/O=Self Signed/CN=Self Signed Root CA' -config openssl.cnf -extensions rootCA_ext

# Create intermediate CA request
openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout interCA.key -sha256 -out interCA.csr -subj '/C=US/ST=US/O=Self Signed/CN=Self Signed Intermediate CA'

# Sign on the intermediate CA
openssl x509 -req -in interCA.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out interCA.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions interCA_ext

# Export the intermediate CA into PFX
openssl pkcs12 -export -out interCA.pfx -inkey interCA.key -in interCA.crt -password 'pass:'

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "================"
Write-Host "Successfully generated root and intermediate CA certificates"
Write-Host "   - rootCA.crt/rootCA.key - Root CA public certificate and private key"
Write-Host "   - interCA.crt/interCA.key - Intermediate CA public certificate and private key"
Write-Host "   - interCA.pfx - Intermediate CA pkcs12 package which could be uploaded to Key Vault"
Write-Host "================"
```

and stored the interCA.pfx in the Key vault as shown below

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "imported-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  certificate {
    contents = filebase64("interCA.pfx")
    password = ""
  }
}
```

and I have created an Azure Firewall Policy

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = "example"
  location            = "West Europe"
  identity {
      type = "UserAssigned"
      user_assigned_identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.test.id]
  }
  sku="Premium"
  tls_certificate{
      key_vault_secret_id = azurerm_key_vault_secret.example.id
      name = "imported-cert"
  }
  intrusion_detection {
      mode="Alert"
      signature_overrides {
          id = "sigOverrideParam1 id (2024897)" 
          state = "Deny" 
      }
      signature_overrides {
          id = "sigOverrideParam2 id (2024898)"
          state = "Alert"
      }
      traffic_bypass {
          name = "SecretBypass"
          protocol ="TCP"
          source_addresses = ["*"]
          destination_addresses =["1.1.1.1"]
          destination_ports = ["80"]
      }
  }
}
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will also need to set a keyvault access policy in your terraform to allow the managed identity to get the secret/certificate from your keyvault. See the [keyvault access policy documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_access_policy) for more details.